# Google analytics not pulling through item price

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I currently have the google analytics ecommerce tracking code pulling through transaction and item details. Everything is working apart from the 'Price' for the item, my script on the confirmation page is as follows...

```
<script>

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||

function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })

(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-21273952-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});

ga('require', 'linker');

ga('linker:autoLink', ['WEBSITE ADDRESS'] );

ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('require', 'ecommerce');

ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {  

'id': '090320151308320974',                       

'revenue': '25' });

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {  

'id': '090320151308320974',  

'name': 'Monthly 25',  

'category': 'Monthly',  

'price': '25' });

ga('ecommerce:send'); 

</script>
```

Can anybody see why this figure wouldn't be pulling through on my analytics dashboard?

Comment: Looks fine at first glance. Have you tried putting in ".00" at the end of the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now got this working, I made the following changes...

- Output the price to 2 decimal places (25.00)
- Added in the sku, quantity and currency type to the add item details

One of these things (or both) managed to fix it and the price is now being pulled through.